# Catching F1 KeyEvent when form has focus.

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I need to catch the F1 KeyEvent when it fires regardless of what has current focus. Currently I have a base class that defines the method that is intended to fire upon F1 keyup. In the child class I am listening for the .KeyUp event and will invoke the parent.

//Base class:

```
protected void GetHelp(String helpIndexParam)
{
    // Logic
}
```

//Child Class:

```
//Declared in constructor of child class
KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyEvent);

private void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{   
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
   {
       base.GetHelp("20");
   }
}
```

Currently, a child form opens and I press F1, nothing happens. Only when I click on a control on the form and then press F1 does the `GetHelp("")` function execute.

Any suggestions appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Are you wanting to catch the key in any form in your app, or any app in Windows?

Comment: Any form in this app where I have defined the above. Which is about half of the child classes currently. I have several child forms implemented currently, and about half of them will react to an F1 press. That's the plan anyhow.

Comment: Have you set `KeyPreview` to true on the form?  This forces all key presses to go to the form's event handlers before they are sent to child controls, and may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. 'KeyPreview = true;' is included in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I learned that because we're using an MDI, the MDI itself was apparently consuming any attempt of catching an F1 click in the child form. I basically had to set it up so that the KeyUp event was defined in the parent form as opposed to the child form, and the child form would simply populate the needed properties from the parent form. That's how I was able to pass a the necessary info to the parent. Also, I had to set focus on a control on the child form just so the whole thing could come together.

I appreciate all the help guys. You all pointed me down the right path in the long run. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you may use [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in the parent form or each child form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == Keys.F1) {
         // Show help;
         return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Or since you are looking for F1 key, you can use the [HelpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
   this.HelpRequested += Form1_HelpRequested;
}
private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent) {
   // Show Help
}
```

Comment: Hm. Would this replace the 'KeyEvent' method that I have listed above? What I mean is would I just stop listening for any method as this override would just handle it? I'll test it out of course both ways, was just curious.

Comment: @TonyD. Yes, ProcessCmdKey  gets called before any key related event gets raised, if it returns true, no KeyDown event will raise. More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/01/24/359334.aspx)

Comment: Member 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys.KeyCode' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. 

It's choking on `keyData.KeyCode`.

Comment: Hm. Child form opens and has focus, F1 pressed, no luck. Once I click on a control, then F1 works as intended.

Comment: I placed the code in the child class. I have to do this because the `GetHelp(")` method that is defined in the parent class takes a param that is specific to the child. Each child that I have this implemented in will need to send a specific param to the parent that is particular to itself. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then If the form that overrides ProcessCmdKey has focus, it should receive the call, try HelpRequested event as I updated the answer.

Comment: Sadly, it has the same results. The F1 is only firing off `GetHelp("");` after I click on a control. Not when the child form loads or even when I click on the form itself. No dice. I click on a control, and poof! method called. Hmm.

Comment: @Tony D Post the code. Did you put the GetHelp in ProcessCmdKey at all?

Comment: yes i did. rendered same results as described above.